# Brown tips on young Norway Spruce

Tags: trees, plant-care, fungus, winter, spruces

Do you think I should treat these young Norway Spruce trees for a fungus or is this browning just from winter or transplant stress?

We live in Minnesota so we have long winters. We planted a long row of young transplants a year ago (May 2021).  They looked good all summer and fall after we planted them.  Now nearly all of them have brown tips! They are not near any road so salt is not a factor.

Any suggestions are much appreciated!
Picture attached.

[image]

Comment: Was it a dry autumn in your location last year? Also, was it an open winter?